# How to get public and secret key from keypair Solders

Tags: keypair, private-key, publickey

Sorry if this is a really basic question but I am new to this.

I am using Solders for python to generate Solana wallets and transactions.
https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/api_reference/keypair.html#solders.keypair.Keypair

When I use the keypair function it seems to work just fine

```
    kp = Keypair()
    which returns something like:
    47LKXoA3MsTRFejTxvDnKUtHDnRtU8417icLSkLzb52MRAdHaZaJAJdEbQmp2VxbDqyH5w8NNZCXGhKBJi9vEo1a
```

The pubkey function to get the public key seems to work just fine

```
    public_key = kp.pubkey()
    which returns:
    gRDrwvJdzgfA9bpGK9pusjQU8bhSjbGmAC1ZnzdS6gY
```

Then using the secret() function to return the secret key doesn't look right

```
    secret_key = kp.secret()
    returns:
    b'\x9b\x83-\xadE\x80\xc7?\x18O}\xd8<\xf3\x0f\xd8HH\xd7%o\t\xf5\xcd\xae\x97L\xe5V\xed\x01\xca'
```

Why does the secret key come out that way?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in bytes and is correct, but my understanding is the keys are commonly Base58 encoded.

You can do the following:

```
import base58 # You'll need to install this

def create_keypair():
    kp = Keypair.generate()
    public_key = kp.public_key
    private_key = kp.secret_key

    return {
        'public_key': base58.b58encode(str(public_key)),
        'private_key': base58.b58encode(private_key)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of methods have been changed as of now (solana.py v0.32, solders v0.20), some were moved out to solders.py.
I also noticed that base58 doesn't decode Solana private key correctly, because I assumed Keypair.secret() is the key. But it's only 32 bytes, and the key is 64 bytes.

As seen in the auto-tests here, `solders.keypair.Keypair` can actually be type-cast to bytes: `bytes(Keypair())`
https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/16656d9e508c5ed9bd237fd94a1c7bfa45eef9be/tests/test_keypair.py#L26

Doing so gives you the full 64 bytes of the private key.

```
# typecast whole Keypair object, not just Keypair.secret(). Very obvious, I know.
rawPK = bytes(solders.keypair.Keypair()) 
pk = base58.b58encode(rawPK).decode()
```

To then restore a keypair from this private key:

```
keypair = solders.keypair.Keypair.from_base58_string(pk)
```

Here's a complete example of how to export and import back a keypair:

```
import base58
import solders

keypair = solders.keypair.Keypair() # generates new keypair
generatedAddr = k.pubkey()

rawPK = bytes(k) 
pk = base58.b58encode(rawPK).decode()

restoredKeypair = solders.keypair.Keypair.from_base58_string(pk)
restoredAddr = nk.pubkey()
restoredCorrectly = (restoredAddr == generatedAddr)
print(restoredCorrectly)
```